# Is the following sentence conveying what I want to express?

Tags: sentence-construction, expressions

I can't think of any better wording to express the sense I want to convey.

> To whatever extent, this thing seems unimportant to you, we need to rethink seriously about it.

The sentence wants to convey that someone X thinks something is not **that** important and another person Y doesn't agree with him, then the later says the former the aforementioned sentence. But to me the sentence looks a bit stilted. Is it natural way to say so?

Comment: The comma after "extent" is definitely superfluous. Depending on what all you're going for, you could say something like "However unimportant this may seem to you, I need you to think seriously about it." or maybe even something like "You may not think this is important, but we need to think seriously about it." In general, it doesn't seem like "rethink" is what you want here. I don't think you can say "rethink about", only "rethink it". Is person Y telling person X to think about it more seriously or inviting X to join Y in thinking about it together?

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung, Person Y is telling person X that they both need to think about it more seriously. Inviting is better way to say.

Comment: @ty, It seems like I was unaware of this usage of "however" which means "to whatever extent" exactly. The "however" word seems to make the sentence natural now.

Comment: Make sure to pair it with "unimportant" side by side and remove any comma before "you". As for the other part, it sort of depends on how much these people have each thought about the thing in the past, what exactly it is that they are thinking about, whether Y is trying to change X's opinion of the thing, etc.

Comment: How about: "However unimportant this thing seems to you, we need to give it some serious thought."

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung, Works with me :-) You can add an answer if you wish pointing the errors with the sentence.

Comment: Hopefully someone else will. It's past my bedtime.

Comment: Leading off with "*However unimportant this seems to you*" is setting an antagonistic tone. You might be better off skipping it and just say, "This is very important and we need to think seriously about it [before <something bad> happens]"

Comment: As WendiKidd [famously wrote](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10945/isnt-it-time-you-stopped-acting-the-goat-is-this-correct-grammatically#comment18339_10950): **Bad comma. Destroy comma.**

Answer (score 2):

> This thing may seem unimportant to you, but I think we need to give it more serious thought.

The word *may* is crucial – it allows you a way out in case you've misunderstood your colleague's viewpoint. It sounds less accusatory.

I believe *to whatever extent* doesn't really add anything to the sentence, and ought to be removed.

I agree that the original sounds a little off, and I believe the two-word phrase *"rethink seriously"* is one of the culprits. I believe *seriously rethink* would sound better, but, in my version, I opted to forgo the verb *rethink*, and use the idiomatic *give thought to* instead.

Answer (score 0):

The precise meaning of your sentence is "We need to do the amount of serious rethinking of the thing that is proportional to the amount that you feel the thing is unimportant."  That isn't really what you want to say in your description.  I'll second J.R.'s suggestion.